# Discrete density plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, density-plot

I have a 2D numpy array and I want to create a discrete density plot using it. Discrete in the sense that at each point `(i,j)` on the plot a dot should be placed whose color should correspond to the value of the `(i,j)` th element of the 2D array. I do not want to use `imshow` because I do not want any interpolation and I also want to control the size the dots to be placed.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `imshow` with `interpolation='nearest'`? Is this close to what you want?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this explicitly for each point, but this will be slow. I think it is best to do it line by line (keep say y fixed) and use the `scatter` function.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

n = 100
x = plt.linspace(0,5, n)
y = plt.linspace(0,5, n)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
for i in range(n):
    y_fixed = y[i] * plt.ones(n)
    z = [(abs(plt.cos(x[i])), 0.0, 0.5) for i in range(n)]
    ax.scatter(x, y_fixed, c=z)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The size is also adjustable in this manor using the `s` argument.

Without any data on how you want the color specified I used an `RGB` value. You may need to normalise however `c=` will take anything pretty much and turn it into a colour, but that may not be very relevant to you.

For more with scatter see the demo [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/screenshots.html)

Comment: I cannot really understand how to implement this in my case as I have a 2D array. Could you show me how to do it with a 2D array?

Comment: You take a slice from your 2D array corresponding to a fixed `y` (or `x`). And use that as the color argument e.g `c=array[i]`.